# Errors with PHP pagination

Tags: php, pagination

I'm trying to create a pagination script for a link in this format: `http://example.com/some-page/1` where `1` will indicate the current page being viewed.

So far, I've been able to come up with a pagination class, here it is below:

```
<?php
class Pagination {
    private $_db,
        $_properties = array(
            'max'       => 5,
            'page'      => 1,
            'total'     => 0,
            'pages'     => 0,
        );

    public function __construct() {
        $this->_db = DB::getInstance();
    }

    public function getPage($page = 2) {
        $this->_properties['page'] = (int)$page;
    }

    public function pageStart() {
        $start = ( $this->getPage() > 1 ) ? ( $this->getPage() * $this->pageLimit() ) : 0;
        return $start;
    }

    public function pageLimit($max = 5) {
        $this->_properties['max'] = (int)$max;
    }

    public function getData($query) {
        $data = $this->_db->query($query . "LIMIT {$this->pageStart()}, {$this->pageLimit()}");

        if ( $data->count() ) {
            $this->_properties['total'] = $data->count();
            return $data->results();
        }
        return false;
    }

    public function totalCount() {
        return $this->_properties['total'];
    }

    public function currentPage() {
        return $this->_properties['page'];
    }

    public function renderLinks() {
        $total = $this->totalCount();
        $perPage = $this->pageLimit();
        $pages = ceil($total / $perPage);
        $currentPage = $this->currentPage();

        $output = "<div class=\"col-md-12 col-xs-12 col-sm-12\">";
        $output .= "<ul class=\"pagination pagination-lg\">";
        $output .= "<li> <a href=\"". $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] . '/' . ($currentPage - 1) ."\"> <i class=\"fa fa-chevron-left\" aria-hidden=\"true\"></i></a></li>";

        for ($i = 1; $i <= $pages ; $i++) { 
            $status = ($currentPage == $i) ? " class=\"active\"" : "";
            $output .= "<li". $status ." > <a href=\"/". $i ."\">". $i ."</a> </li>";

        }

        $output .= "<li><a href=\"/". $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] . '/' . $i ."\"> <i class=\"fa fa-chevron-right\" aria-hidden=\"true\"></i></a></li>";
        $output .= "<ul>";
        $output .= "</div>";

        return $output;
    }
}
```

And I call it in the page where I need it like so:

```
$userServices = new Pagination();
$userServices->getPage($thirdvar);
$userServices->pageLimit(2);
$servicesData = $userServices->getData("SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `id` = 4");
```

Then I do a foreach loop to get the contents of the `$serviceData`, like so:

```
foreach ( $serviceData as $service ) {
    // output content here
}
```

Then for the navigation links:

```
<?php echo $userServices->renderLinks(); ?>
```

When I ran the page, I got an error: `Warning: Division by zero in C:\xampp7\htdocs\directory\model\Pagination.php on line 49`. That is, where I have `$pages = ceil($total / $perPage);` and also this error: `Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 65011744 bytes) in C:\xampp7\htdocs\directory\model\Pagination.php on line 58`, where I have `$output .= "<li". $status ." > <a href=\"/". $i ."\">". $i ."</a> </li>";`.

So far, when I manually input a number to replace the `$pages = ceil($total / 4);`, the errors disappear, but I do not get the data in the page.

Where am I doing it wrong?

**EDIT**

So after making some corrections (based on answers and comments), I figured out that the reason why no data is being populated is from this line: `$data = $this->_db->query($query . "LIMIT $this->pageStart(), $this->pageLimit()");`. For *who-know-why*, I don't know why `$this->pageStart()` and `$this->pageLimit()` are not returning any values, thereby making the query to fail.

Can someone please point me to the right path?

Comment: change the default value of  `'pages'     => 1,`

Comment: @AlivetoDie, I don't think I even used that in the class. But I just changed the value, and it still returned the same error.

Comment: what is the value of `$thirdvar`? where you defined it?

Comment: Please check my updated question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after so much debugging, and also from the insights given in some comments, I was able to figure out the problem of my pagination class.

First, I updated my `getData()` method to:

```
public function getData($query) {
    $data = $this->_db->query("{$query} LIMIT {$this->pageStart()}, {$this->pageLimit()}");

    if ( $data->count() ) {
        return $data->results();
    }
    $tQuery = $this->_db->query("SELECT FOUND_ROWS() AS total");
    $this->_properties['total'] = $tQuery->first()->total;
}
```

and then called it in my page using:

```
$servicesData = $userServices->getData("SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS * FROM `table` WHERE `id` = 1");
```

Also, I added some new methods `renderPage()`, `renderLimit()`, `baseUrl()` and `renderUrl()` which will return the values of `getPage()`, `pageLimit()`, get the url structure that will be entered, and return the value of `baseUrl()` respectively.

Then I also updated the `renderLinks()` method like so:

```
public function renderLinks() {
    $total = $this->totalCount();
    $perPage = $this->renderLimit();
    $pages = ceil($total / $perPage);
    $currentPage = $this->renderPage();
    $prevCalc = $currentPage - 1;
    $prevStat = ($prevCalc == 0) ? "" : " href=\"". $this->renderUrl() . $prevCalc ."\"";
    $nextCalc = $currentPage + 1;
    $nextStat = ($nextCalc > $pages) ? "" : " href=\"". $this->renderUrl() . $nextCalc ."\"";

    $output = "<div class=\"col-md-12 col-xs-12 col-sm-12\">";
    $output .= "<ul class=\"pagination pagination-lg\">";
    $output .= "<li> <a". $prevStat ."> <i class=\"fa fa-chevron-left\" aria-hidden=\"true\"></i></a></li>";

    for ($i = 1; $i <= $pages ; $i++) { 
        $status = ($currentPage == $i) ? " class=\"active\"" : "";
        $output .= "<li". $status ." > <a href=\"". $this->renderUrl() . $i ."\">". $i ."</a> </li>";

    }

    $output .= "<li><a". $nextStat ."> <i class=\"fa fa-chevron-right\" aria-hidden=\"true\"></i></a></li>";
    $output .= "<ul>";
    $output .= "</div>";

    return $output;
}
```

So in all, my **Pagination Class** looks like so:

```
<?php
class Pagination {
    private $_db,
        $_properties = array(
            'max'       => 5,
            'page'      => 1,
            'total'     => 4,
            'base_url'  => '',
        );

    public function __construct() {
        $this->_db = DB::getInstance();
    }

    public function getPage($page = null) {
        return( $page && $page != "" ) ? $this->_properties['page'] = (int)$page : $this->_properties['page'];
    }

    public function renderPage() {
        return $this->_properties['page'];
    }

    public function pageLimit($max = null) {
        return( $max ) ? $this->_properties['max'] = (int)$max : $this->_properties['max'];
    }

    public function renderLimit() {
        return $this->_properties['max'];
    }

    public function pageStart() {
        return( $this->renderPage() > 1 ) ? ($this->renderPage() * $this->renderLimit()) - $this->pageLimit() : 0;
    }

    public function getData($query) {
        $data = $this->_db->query("{$query} LIMIT {$this->pageStart()}, {$this->pageLimit()}");

        if ( $data->count() ) {
            return $data->results();
        }
        $tQuery = $this->_db->query("SELECT FOUND_ROWS() AS total");
        $this->_properties['total'] = $tQuery->first()->total;
    }

    public function totalCount() {
        return $this->_properties['total'];
    }

    public function baseUrl($url = null) {
        return( $url ) ? $this->_properties['base_url'] = escape_url($url) : $this->_properties['base_url'];
    }

    public function renderUrl() {
        return $this->_properties['base_url'];
    }

    public function renderLinks() {
        $total = $this->totalCount();
        $perPage = $this->renderLimit();
        $pages = ceil($total / $perPage);
        $currentPage = $this->renderPage();
        $prevCalc = $currentPage - 1;
        $prevStat = ($prevCalc == 0) ? "" : " href=\"". $this->renderUrl() . $prevCalc ."\"";
        $nextCalc = $currentPage + 1;
        $nextStat = ($nextCalc > $pages) ? "" : " href=\"". $this->renderUrl() . $nextCalc ."\"";

        $output = "<div class=\"col-md-12 col-xs-12 col-sm-12\">";
        $output .= "<ul class=\"pagination pagination-lg\">";
        $output .= "<li> <a". $prevStat ."> <i class=\"fa fa-chevron-left\" aria-hidden=\"true\"></i></a></li>";

        for ($i = 1; $i <= $pages ; $i++) { 
            $status = ($currentPage == $i) ? " class=\"active\"" : "";
            $output .= "<li". $status ." > <a href=\"". $this->renderUrl() . $i ."\">". $i ."</a> </li>";

        }

        $output .= "<li><a". $nextStat ."> <i class=\"fa fa-chevron-right\" aria-hidden=\"true\"></i></a></li>";
        $output .= "<ul>";
        $output .= "</div>";

        return $output;
    }
}
```

Hope it helps some other person(s) out there.

Answer (score 2):

`$perPage = $this->pageLimit();`

Yet the `pageLimit()` function doesn't return anything. That's the problem.

Comment: I've added `return $this->_properties['max'];` to the pageLimit()... Now the errors are gone, but the data is not populated.

Comment: total and pages are set to zero too?

Comment: I've already assigned another value to it here: `$this->_properties['total'] = $data->count();`

Answer (score 0):

This should fix the 2nd error

```
ini_set('memory_limit','16M');
```

Instead of 16M pass hight value that is required(I left the math for you). But this is not a good practice make you code more efficient.

Pu this before the 49 line

```
die($perPage);
```

And put the output. So that I can help you.

EDIT:

You need to work on you code lot of issues. Remove the die();

Comment: No it will not because it's created by first one itself (division by 0)

Comment: Error went away, but nothing was displayed.

Comment: After careful observations Of code I saw you $total var will always be zero because it is taking the initial value zero. You need get the query from db.

Comment: `$this->totalCount()` is returning the value of `$this->_properties['total']`, which `$data->count()` has been assigned to it. Please what do you mean by `$this->pageLimit()` method never defined, @RajendranNadar?